# Find same word in named ranges

Tags: vba, range

End game here is to take action if the word "NOTE:" appears more than once in named ranges, but first I'm just trying to get the count of the word "NOTE:" in each range.  The first code works, but when I try to replace the range with a named range (first is Range4, others will be variable), I'm getting an "Object required" error.

First code

```
Dim iVal As Integer
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.COUNTIF(Range("A1:A10"),"NOTE:")
```

Code I want

```
Dim iVal As Integer
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf((Range4), "NOTE:")
```

Like I said, the end game is to use something like Range(a) so that the a can be a variable as my named ranges are "Range1, Range2, Range3, etc...), but I'm having trouble even getting the first named range to pull the count of NOTE: even without a variable.

Comment: is `Range4` a named range, as in is it listed in the named ranges in excel, or is a variable in vba that is declared a range?

Comment: It's a named range.  I'm trying to figure this out, so I just named a range of cells in column A and tried to use that for the named range just to get through that part.

Comment: `Range("Range4")`

Comment: That worked!  Thank you! Just out of curiousity, if I wanted to go the variable route, do you think the best way is to do Range("Range" & n)?  Would that work you think/is that the best way to do this?

Comment: No, that will not work, that way if that is the method you want then named ranges is best, just more manual set up.